# Breaking when a certain amount of bytes is allocated

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks, msvcrt

`_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` if you didn't know, is a function that dumps all the memory leaks in a program. Mine currently displays that I have a  3632062 byte memory leak (it's not being deallocated).

I was wondering:
Is there any way to cause Visual C++ Express to break when a certain amount of bytes has been allocated? That way I could break when 3632062 bytes have been allocated, then read the stack trace to see where I allocated it.

This is currently the only method I can think of for finding where the memory is being allocated so I can fix it. I've been searching my code a lot but I can't find anywhere where I would need to allocate  3632062 bytes (since the only file I load is 2767136 bytes..) although I am certain the leak is related to the file I'm operating on.

Any ideas for finding the source of the memory leak? I'm using Native C++, Visual C++ 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using [_CrtSetAllocHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/820k4tb8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to track the total memory usage.

[UMDH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558947%28VS.85%29.aspx) will give you a list of allocated blocks in all heaps.  This might be what you want, since breaking on hitting a given total alloc threshold will not tell you where all of the blocks were allocated.

Comment: Wow this is perfect for what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've mostly used it for leak tracking (comparing successive snapshots) but it's also good for attribution.  Make sure all your symbols are correct and accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I have previously used this [simple memory leak detector](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=482850) with good success for finding memory leaks.